# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof

Tags: real-analysis

I found an interesting problem in my textbook, it asks to prove the following statement:

> If $f'(x_{0}) >0$, then there is a $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)<f(x_{0})$ if $x_{0}- \delta < x <x_{0}$, and $f(x) > f(x_{0})$ if $x_{0} <x < x_{0} + \delta$.

How would one prove this from the definitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $f'(x_0) > 0$, we can find $\delta > 0$ so that:
$$
|x - x_0| < \delta \implies \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} > 0
$$
(why?)

Now, the quotient above is positive iff the numerator and denominator have the same sign. Split this into two cases and handle each case separately to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Let $m=f'(x_0)>0$.  Suppose by way of contradiction that $f(x)>f(x_0)$ did not hold in some interval $(x_0, x_0+\delta)$.  Then there would be some sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ such that $x_i>x_0$, $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}x_i=x_0$, and $f(x_i)<f(x_0)$.  But then this contradicts $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0+}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=m>0$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x_0)>0$ then for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$, whit $x<x_0$, such that 
\begin{align}
0<|x-x_0|<\delta
 \implies
&
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f'(x_0) \right|<\epsilon 
\\
-\delta <x-x_0<\delta
\implies
&
0<f'(x_0) -\epsilon <\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} <+f'(x_0) +\epsilon
\\
x_0-\delta <x<x_0+\delta
\implies
&
0<f'(x_0)(x-x_0)-\epsilon (x-x_0)+f(x_0)< f(x) 
\end{align}